# jQuery - Access object key and value

Tags: jquery

I m trying to use the keys and values from the `coArray` object as the options being appended to the select element, and I'm not sure how to access them. Now the dropdown is empty. No value and no name.

```
var coArray = new Object();
//Object {1: "United States", 7: "Andorra", 162: "Northern Mariana Islands", 178: "Romania"}

    $.each(coArray, function(key, value) {
        if(this.key != 0)
        {
            options.append($("<option />").val(this.key).text(this.value));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `this` from everywhere, use `key` and `value` params:

```
var coArray = new Object();
//Object {1: "United States", 7: "Andorra", 162: "Northern Mariana Islands", 178: "Romania"}

$.each(coArray, function (key, value) {
    if (key != 0) {
        options.append($("<option />").val(key).text(value));
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pwzjd846/)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, `key` and `value` are variables. They are passed in as parameters (which is what `function(key, value)` means).

```
function(key, value)
{
    if(key != 0)
    {
        options.append($("<option />").val(key).text(value));
    }
}
```

The result is that you do not need to use `this` to get scope of them.

It sounds like you could read up on what [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) does.